# Django restframework: ReadOnlyModelViewSet create HTTP_403 but expected HTTP_405

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I am creating a REST-API with django and the django rest framework, therefore I am using `ReadOnlyModelViewSet`. In my unit test for testing `create / POST` method, I am expecting `HTTP_405_METHOD_NOT_ALLOWED` but actually it is `HTTP_403_FORBIDDEN`. For the `update / PUT` it is `HTTP_405` as expected. Is this behavior the default behavior or do I have a dumb bug?

And yes the user is authenticated.

The Viewset:

```
class StudentSolutionReadOnlyModelViewSet(viewsets.ReadOnlyModelViewSet):
    queryset = StudentSolution.objects.all()
    serializer_class = StudentSolutionSerializer

    def get_permissions(self):
        if self.request.method == 'POST':
            return (permissions.IsAuthenticated(), )
        return (permissions.IsAuthenticated(), IsStudentSolutionOwnerOrAdmin(),)

    def get_queryset(self):
        if self.request.user.is_staff:
            return StudentSolution.objects.all(
                course_assignment=self.kwargs['course_assignment_pk']
                ).order_by('student__last_name', 'course_assignment__due_date')
        return StudentSolution.objects.filter(
            student=self.request.user,
            course_assignment=self.kwargs['course_assignment_pk']
            ).order_by('course_assignment__due_date')
```

---

**Edit 1:**

```
class StudentSolutionReadOnlyModelViewSetTests(TestCase):
    def setup(self): 
        #[..]

    def test_create_user_not_allowed(self):
        data = {
            'course_assignment': self.course_assignment.id,
            'student': self.user.id
        }

        url = self.generate_url(self.course_assignment.id)

        self.csrf_client.credentials(HTTP_AUTHORIZATION='JWT ' + self.user_token)
        resp = self.csrf_client.post(
            self.url,
            data=json.dumps(data),
            content_type='application/json'
        )
        self.assertEqual(resp.status_code, status.HTTP_405_METHOD_NOT_ALLOWED)
```

I am using the same authentication and csrf stuff for all methods, as well as `generate_url` method.

Comment: The `POST` request you send, is it authenticated?

Comment: yes it is authenticated

Comment: Ok, that's weird, try to debug to see if you're getting in the conditional block `self.request.method == 'POST'` in the first place.

Comment: Yes, I am getting inside the block. I also have changed the permissions for every case to `permissions.AllowAny()` and still the same behavior

Comment: i want you to add a conditional block for `PUT` method and see if it's behaviour changed. Also check the **settings.py** file for any `permissions`

Comment: `PUT` is still working as expected. In the settings I have only the default permission `IsAuthenticated`.

Comment: Can you also add the unit test snippet ?

Comment: @JerinPeterGeorge  I did

Comment: What will happen if you remove the entire `get_permissions()` method from view ?

Comment: Same behavior...

Comment: oops.. What is the value of `url` in you test ?

Comment: thats it. Thanks, I was using `self.url` instead of `url`. Which is the base url, there `POST` is allowed, but forbidden for this user.